# Deixando a altura da div igual a largura usando somente css

Tags: css

Digamos que eu tenha 4 div, com a propriedade `width:25%`. Em um espaço de 1000px, esses 25% representariam 250px.

```
<div style="width:1000px"></div>
    <div style="width:25%;"></div>
    <div style="width:25%;"></div>
    <div style="width:25%;"></div>
    <div style="width:25%;"></div>
</div>
```

Usando somente o css, seria possível "capturar" a largura da div responsiva em pixels e aplicar esse valor capturado a propriedade `height`.

Seria algo como:

```
<div style="width:1000px"></div>
    <div style="width:25%; height: 250px"></div>
    <div style="width:25%; height: 250px"></div>
    <div style="width:25%; height: 250px"></div>
    <div style="width:25%; height: 250px"></div>
</div>
```

> Minha dúvida se resume apenas ao css, se é possível fazer isso usando apenas css, pois sei que é possível alcançar esse objetivo usando js.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem uma forma bem simples para isso uma é usando `calc(),` e `flex` e `CSS variable`. A outra é o `hake` do `padding` e mantendo o *aspect-ratio* de forma mais responsiva, pois vc vai ver que o `padding-top` que vai criar a altura é relativo a largura do *container*

**Técnica com `calc(),` e `flex` e `CSS variable`**

Repare que eu vou declara um valor na variável `--debug: ;` no caso `1000px` e depois vou declara `var(--debug)` como `width` e no `height` vou usar a função `calc()` do CSS para dividir `var(--debug)` por 4, fazendo assim `calc(var(--debug) / 4)`.

Repare no Gif abaixo que conforme eu vou mudando o valor da variável `--debug` a largura e proporcionalmente a altura tb vai mudando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então o que temos é um valor só que é declarado na variável, essa variável eu uso como `width` e essa mesmo variável do `width` eu dividido por 4 no `heigth`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja eu vc ainda pode usar um `Media Queries` para mudar o valor de `--debug` e assim mudar todo o *container* de forma proporcional alterando apenas um valor. Vc teria algo como esse CSS abaixo. Lembrando ainda que vc pode declarar essas variáveis direto no `:root` como vc pode ler aqui [O que significa o -- especificado no :root do css do bootstrap?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298995/o-que-significa-o-especificado-no-root-do-css-do-bootstrap/298998#298998)

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    --debug: 768px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    --debug: 320px;
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima *(Exiba em página toda para ver a responsividade)*:

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .container {
    --debug: 1000px;
    width: var(--debug);
    height: calc(var(--debug) / 4);
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
  }

.item {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    --debug: 600px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    --debug: 480px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">item no container</div>
  <div class="item">item no container</div>
  <div class="item">item no container</div>
  <div class="item">item no container</div>
</div>
```

---

**Técnica que deixa o *aspect-ratio* do `container` usando `padding-top`**

Repare que eu tenho agora dois *containers*, um `.container` e dentro dele o *container* `.pai` que é o pai dos `.item`.

O `padding-top` é relativo a largura do elemento, então eu tenho um primeiro *container* sem largura definida e como um `padding-top` de `25%`, ou seja `1/4` da altura do próprio elemento. Para esse padding não empurrar o conteúdo interno para baixo eu precisei de outro *container*, o *container* `.pai` que está com `position:absolute` e tem `100%` da `height` e `width` do `.container` principal que é o pai dele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse *container* `.pai` tem `display:flex` e os filhos deles `flex:1` para ficarem divididos igualmente em 4 porções do `.pai`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  /* overflow: auto; */
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding-top: 25%;
}
.pai {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  flex:1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pai">
      <div class="item">item no container</div>
      <div class="item">item no container</div>
      <div class="item">item no container</div>
      <div class="item">item no container</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sem usar *flexbox*, você pode usar `float: left` nas divs e `overflow: auto` no contêiner, utilizando a técnica do *aspect ratio* `1:1` com `padding-top` com o mesmo valor do `width`, ou seja, `25%`:

```css
.boxes{
   overflow: auto;
}

.boxes div{
   width: 25%;
   padding-top: 25%;
   float: left;
}

/* abaixo é só para ilustração, não inclua no CSS */
.boxes div:nth-child(odd){
   background: #ddd;
}

.boxes div:nth-child(even){
   background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<p>Parágrafo acima</p>
<div class="boxes">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
<p>Parágrafo abaixo</p>
```

Desta forma temos 4 divs com 25% da tela (ou do contêiner), uma ao lado da outra e com a mesma altura.

Caso queira adicionar conteúdo nas divs (texto ou imagem), pode inserir spans dentro das divs filhas, com posicionamento absoluto e com as dimensões 100% largura e altura definidos pelas propriedades `top`, `right`, `bottom`, e `left` em `0`:

```css
.boxes{
   overflow: auto;
}

.boxes div{
   position: relative;
   width: 25%;
   padding-top: 25%;
   float: left;
}

.boxes div span{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   padding: 10px; /* OPCIONAL: espaçamento das bordas */
}

/* abaixo é só para ilustração, não inclua no CSS */
.boxes div:nth-child(odd){
   background: #ddd;
}

.boxes div:nth-child(even){
   background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<p>Parágrafo acima</p>
<div class="boxes">
   <div>
      <span>Texto ou imagem</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span>Texto ou imagem</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span>Texto ou imagem</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span>Texto ou imagem</span>
   </div>
</div>
<p>Parágrafo abaixo</p>
```

> Se for adicionar bordas nas divs, coloque `box-sizing: border-box`
>   para que as mesmas sejam aplicadas nos limites de 25% das divs, e não
>   na parte de fora. Por exemplo:

```css
.boxes{
   overflow: auto;
}

.boxes div{
   position: relative;
   width: 25%;
   padding-top: 25%;
   float: left;
   border: 2px solid #444;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxes div span{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   padding: 10px;
}

/* abaixo é só para ilustração, não inclua no CSS */
.boxes div:nth-child(odd){
   background: #ddd;
}

.boxes div:nth-child(even){
   background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<p>Parágrafo acima</p>
<div class="boxes">
   <div>
      <span>Texto ou imagem</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span>Texto ou imagem</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span>Texto ou imagem</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span>Texto ou imagem</span>
   </div>
</div>
<p>Parágrafo abaixo</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Se você souber a largura do container na unidade de medida `vw`, basta usar esse valor dividido por 4 nos filhos, por exemplo, se o container for do tamanho máximo da tela, a altura será de 25vw, se o container for de 80% da tela (ou 80 vw), a altura será de 20vw, etc

Isso porque o valor usado pelo vw é o mesmo independentemente se usado na altura ou largura, assim como o `vh` e o `vmin`

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.row {
  width: 80vw;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10vw;
  padding: 0;
}
div.col {
  width: 20vw; /* ou 25% */
  height: 20vw; /* ou calc(80vw / 4) */
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid darkred;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá, tente dessa forma e veja se resolve seu problema.

```
<div style="width:100px; height: 400px; background: #4a4a4a">
    <div style="width:25%; margin: 1px; padding-bottom: 25%; background: #fff"></div>
    <div style="width:25%; margin: 1px; padding-bottom: 25%; background: #fff"></div>
    <div style="width:25%; margin: 1px; padding-bottom: 25%; background: #fff"></div>
    <div style="width:25%; margin: 1px; padding-bottom: 25%; background: #fff"></div>
</div>
```